# How do I change the provider part in unique name of an App that I am developing using App Designer for the Unified Interface?

Tags: interface, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-uci

I am trying to create an app for a client as a part of move to Unified Interface. When I try to create the app from App Designer, I see the unique name as "new_xxxx". I want to change the "new_" part to "xyz_". How do I accomplish this?
I want to change the highlighted part.

[change name of provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G04jJ.png)

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify my answer?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. I used the existing solution and it worked.

Comment: Good, can you upvote/mark the answer & help others to find it useful..

Answer (score 0):

Create a new solution or use an existing solution to build a new Model driven app. Make sure right publisher is used on solution to get the desired prefix (non new_).

[image]

[image]